# Node.JS + Puppeteer: browser.close freezes process

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I have a really simple function I'm running.

```
module.exports.test = async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch(puppetOptions);
    try {
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.goto('https://google.com');
        // helper function that pauses for five seconds before moving on
        await pause(5000);
        await browser.close();
        console.log('browser closed');
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        await browser.close();
    }
}
```

I run it from my `index.js` file:

```
const server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000, () => {
    test();    
});
```

Now I run it in my terminal with `node index.js`. It opens a browser. It opens a new page and navigates to Google. It waits five seconds. It closes the browser. Everything appears great. I hit `ctrl + c` in my terminal to stop the process, but nothing happens. Typically this works. If I remove the `browser.close` function, `ctrl + c` goes back to working as expected, and ends the process. This function I'm running is the result of me breaking down a more complex function that appears to have a memory leak, so it really seems that `browser.close` is the culprit. For the life of me though, I can't figure out why it would be causing an issue when simplified this much. This is happening in both `headless`, and `headfull` modes. Here are the puppeteer launch options:

```
puppetOptions = {
    defaultViewport: null,
    args: [
        "--incognito",
        "--no-sandbox",
        "--single-process",
        "--no-zygote"
    ],
}

puppetOptionsHeadfull = {
    headless: false,
    executablePath: 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe',
}
```

EDIT: I tried this in my bash terminal as well and have the same issue. When I try to manually close the terminal to abort it, an error pops up.

```
Processes are running in session:
| WPID PID COMMAND
| 10900 1122 winpty node.exe index.js
Close anyway?
```

EDIT 2: Narrowed this down to it being an issue with `puppeteer-extra` most likely, however, it seems like a bug in the core package. Fairly recent open issue on their repo that reflects this bug found here: https://github.com/berstend/puppeteer-extra/issues/421

I'll leave this question open just in case anyone else stumbles on it with the same issue, they don't pull their hair out debugging it.

Answer (score 2):

It is depends on flag combination. If we need headless mode and --no-sandbox flag, then try this puppeteer launch code:

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true, args: ['--no-sandbox','--single-process', '--no-zygote'], ignoreHTTPSErrors: true });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
...
await browser.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

I have been having this issue as well. It seems for me that the two arguments '--no-sandbox', and '--disable-setuid-sandbox' are culprits, although it's not intuitive why that would be the case. Try removing the no sandbox argument

Comment: Worth noting, if you remove `--no-sandbox`, you must also remove `--no-zygote`.  I encountered this error when I only removed `--no-sandbox`: `Zygote cannot be disabled if sandbox is enabled. Use --no-zygote together with --no-sandbox`